# How to use the GattManager from Nordic

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm quite new to Android programming and I would like to use the GattManager from Nordic (https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/puck-central-android/tree/master/PuckCentral/app/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/puckcentral/bluetooth/gatt) in my test application.

The main question is whether I need to copy just the bluetooth folder into my project or I need the whole repository.